# Simplify duplication in repetitive method call

Tags: c#

I have a repetitive method call that looks like this:

```
GroupGenerator(param1, enum.val1, true, false, false)
```

With each call the boolean values change to cover all possible combinations,

```
true, false, false
true, true, false
etc etc
```

Is there a neater way of doing this without writing the line `GroupGenerator(param1...` over and over again?

Any help/opinion much appreciated.

Comment: You can call `GroupGenerator` via another method which dispatch call to multiple combinations.

Comment: It appears that you should be handling boolean combinations inside the method if all of them are needed required, this ensures all modules have a single responsibility. Also, this question is better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 7):

`true, false, false` is effectively `100` in binary, `true, true, false` is `110`. With this in mind,

```
public static bool GetBit(byte b, int bitNumber) 
{
  return (b & (1 << bitNumber)) != 0;
}

for(byte n = 0; n < 8; n++)
  GroupGenerator(param1, enum.val1, GetBit(n, 0), GetBit(n, 1), GetBit(n, 2));
```